# Response.Redirect("Default.aspx"); not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, button

After the user registers im trying to redirect the client to the default page and the easiest way to do it seems to be adding this line at the end of the submit button:

```
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

but its not working, it stays in the same page without showing any errors.

I've also tried with :

```
Server.Transfer("Default.aspx");
```

without any luck.

Heres the full code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Carnisoftix
{
    public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            carniuser oUsr = new carniuser();
            oUsr.Email = txtEmail.Text;
            oUsr.Name = txtName.Text;
            oUsr.Pass = txtPassword.Text;
            oUsr.Phone = txtPhone.Text;
            oUsr.Usrname = txtUsername.Text;
            oUsr.Address = txtAddress.Text;
            oUsr.SpecialK = Convert.ToInt16(txtSpecial.Text);
            oUsr.Auth = 1;
            regUsr(oUsr);

            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
        public static int regUsr(carniuser oUsr)
        {
            int oNum;
            SqlConnection oConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=L:\\Apps\\VS Projects\\Carnisoftix\\CarniDb.mdf;Database=CarniDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
            string oSql = "ADDUSR";
            SqlCommand oCom = new SqlCommand(oSql, oConnection);
            oCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@useremail", oUsr.Email);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userpass", oUsr.Pass);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", oUsr.Name);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", oUsr.Phone);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", oUsr.Address);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", oUsr.Usrname);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@authority", oUsr.Auth);
            oCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@special", oUsr.SpecialK);
            SqlParameter oReturn = new SqlParameter("@out", SqlDbType.Int);
            oReturn.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            oCom.Parameters.Add(oReturn);
            oConnection.Open();
            oCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            oNum = (int)oCom.Parameters["@out"].Value;
            oConnection.Close();
            return oNum;
        }
    }
    /*@useremail,
    @username,
    @userpass,
    @name,
    @phone,
    @address,
    @authority,
    @special*/
    public class carniuser
    {
        private string email, usrname, pass, name, phone, address;
        private int authority, specialK;
        public carniuser()
        {
            email = "";
            usrname = "";
            pass = "";
            name = "";
            phone = "";
            address = "";
            authority = 1;
            specialK = 1;
        }
        public string Email
        {
            get { return email; }
            set { email = value; }
        }
        public string Pass
        {
            get { return pass; }
            set { pass = value; }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
        public string Phone
        {
            get { return phone; }
            set { phone = value; }
        }
        public string Address
        {
            get { return address; }
            set { address = value; }
        }
        public string Usrname
        {
            get { return usrname; }
            set { usrname = value; }
        }
        public int Auth
        {
            get { return authority; }
            set { authority = value; }
        }
        public int SpecialK
        {
            get { return specialK; }
            set { specialK = value; }
        }

        public carniuser(string email, string usrname, string pass, string name, string phone, string address, int authority, int specialK)
        {
            //string _email = email;
            Email = email;
            Usrname = usrname;
            Pass = pass;
            Name = name;
            Phone = phone;
            Address = address;
            Auth = authority;
            SpecialK = specialK;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are actually submitting the data? Did you put a breakpoint and see that the event handler fired?

Comment: Try this->`Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx",true);`

Comment: Are you sure the path is right? Default.aspx must be in the same folder as the current page.

Comment: Or your Default.aspx folder server path.`Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("~/path/Default.aspx"),true)`

Comment: may you please tell me that your Default page is placed in root folder or placed inside any folder.

Comment: The data is being added to the database and the path seems to be right because im using Response.Redirect(Register.aspx); in the Default.aspx web form.

Comment: Check the AutoPostback event of your button, if at all it is posting back.

Comment: try a breakpoint and see if it is hitting the breakpoint. If your breakpoint comes after `regUsr(oUsr);` then your code works otherwise there is something wrong in your code

Comment: @DotNetDreamer its not hitting the breakpoint, what should i do? It is still adding the input to the database.

Comment: @GustavoRodríguezSuarez, show your html code where a button is declared

Comment: `<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
            onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />`

Comment: double click on your button and check that it hits on btnSubmit_Click event or not and where is your Default page exist,it's on root or iinside any folder.

Comment: It does, its even adding everything to the database, i can check it on the sql server management studio with select * from users.

Comment: try to change `onclick` to `OnClick`

Comment: ok do one thing instead of redirecting your page,this time redirect Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com", true);,and check after saving data is it accessing google website..plz try

Comment: Response.Redirect("google.com";, true); didnt work either

Comment: try to change `CauseValidation="false"` of the button

Comment: Maybe there is some issue with the debugger or chrome or the database or the connection to the database?

Comment: @DotNetDreamer still the same

Comment: try to put your button click code inside try{} catch(){} block for the exact error..

Comment: Okay i fixed it restarting VS 2010, i dont know what was causing the issue. I would like to know though.

Comment: @GustavoRodríguezSuarez - There is no way of knowing considering the code was correct.  Although the method being a static int makes sense considering you don't even capture the returned value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must know where is the registration page? Default.aspx is in different folder?

But Try this

```
Response.Redirect("../Default.aspx");
```

or

```
Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Tried both, they are on the same directory. Im starting to think i should restart VS.

Comment: You try to trace the code? Maybe there's an error?

Comment: right click on project folder in solution explorer and click on clean

Comment: I tried cleaning the project and it didnt work, after restarting VS 2010 is working properly now, intriguing.

Comment: Is your problem solved now?

Comment: Yes its solved, i dont know why but i had to close everything, VS 2010, sql server management studio 2008 express and chrome, opened it again and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i remember, the submit button will cause a postback, which will execute your code, and reload the page afterwards. Try adding this to your Page_Load:

```
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

Comment: The redirect is already inside the button click (that is called only on PostBack)

Comment: IsPostBack has no role in this case....

Comment: if a button is clicked, it is already in post back. remove the IsPostBack

Comment: I just tried adding it inside the page_load without any luck

Comment: Is not it wrong! Because of the form will be 4-5 every time :) go to "Default.apx" page?

Comment: when you click on submit button then first it will call page_load and then it will call button click event.so postback problem in submit button how happen..