# Redirecting to up one level with Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have user control that uses a `Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")`. The problem starts when this control is used in files that are located in subdirectories and I try to redirect up a level.

Conversely, if I use `../Default.aspx`, redirects in the top level will break.

Is there another way to code this?

Comment: you can use `Request.ApplicationPath`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to go up level directory or your Default.aspx page in main directory
go at link https://stackoverflow.com/a/16277982/7300644

or use

```
Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

or

```
Response.Redirect("../Default.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use complete path, something like this,

```
Response.Redirect("~/directory/subdirectory/Default.aspx");
```

Comment: Yes, but the default.aspx is in `directory` not in `subdirectory` that's not going to work.

Comment: try `Response.Redirect("~/directory/Default.aspx");`

Comment: I just used above path as an example, depending on where your default.aspx file is stored your path may vary, did you try using the complete path? does it work?

Comment: @Damith, again that doesn't work if I'm calling the redirect from `~/directory/admin/admin.aspx`